# sanitation of user input nodeJs - Express

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm running through some code and I'm questioning the level of validation / sanitation being applied on the API endpoint. (using Nodejs/Express)

```
customerRoute.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;

 if (!validate.STRING(firstName)) {
        res.apiError(messages.server.invalid_request);

    } else if (!validate.STRING(lastName)) {
        res.apiError(messages.server.invalid_request);

    } else if (!validate.STRING(email)) {
        res.apiError(messages.server.invalid_request);

    } else if (!validate.EMAIL(email)) {
        res.apiError(messages.shared.invalid_email);

 } else {

var schemaObj = {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email

};
```

And custom modules validation:

```
module.exports.STRING = function(str) {
        if (typeof str !== 'string') {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    module.exports.EMAIL = function(email) {
        const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }
```

Currently, it is possible to add script tags in the name fields, which gets added to the DB. However trying to add a '<' in the email gets blocked.
I have considered express-validator to satanize. (The original developer added the above custom code and felt nothing else was needed - I think he wanted to keep the footprint down)
From the documentation (https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#sanitizers) it mentions

> escaping - replace <, >, &, ', " and / with HTML entities.

Does this mean it will allow these tags into the DB and is it suitable for my needs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using custom modules for validation and sanitation, I suggest you use [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) it has in-built functions for normalizing emails as well as multiple other operations.